# If cell is empty, copy the next(right 1,2,3)cell and paste, how to make it?

Tags: excel, vba

```
  A COLUMN   B COLUMN   C COLUMN  D COLUMN        
    20          2           3       4
    60          G           2       5
                5           6       8 
    20          G           R       2
    
    -->
    
    A COLUMN   B COLUMN   C COLUMN  D COLUMN     
    20          2           3       4
    60          G           2       5
     5          6           8        
    20          G           R       2
```

I want to make it as above!

By using vba(code), i would like to figure it out.

If cell is empty in a column, the cell next 1, 2, 3(rightside) copy and paste to the empty cell.

please help me...

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. You will not find someone who does all the work for you. We would need you to show what you have tried in VBA first. You will need to learn how to write a macro that reads out a cell. Then you will need to find out how to write a macro that copies a cell into another one. Look here for a quick overview: https://www.excelhowto.com/macros/excel-vba-copy-and-paste-a-range/  Look here for a really really good guide  https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-copy/

Comment: In your example above `Range("A3").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft` will remove the empty cell in A3 and automatically shift the cells right to it one left. Now you just need to find out how to loop through cells and how to check if they are empty. Do some research on that (you will find many tutorials for this) and then try something on your own. If you get stuck on errors come back with your code/attempt and ask a question to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you select column "A" and the hit F5=>special cells=>blanks.
Right click on one of the blank cells and select delete=>shift cells left

[image]

Here is the code for that

```
    Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```